# In an objective c ios project, where to find the database schema?

Tags: ios, sqlite

I know virtually no objective c, but I'm working on rewriting an old ios project.

In Rails, in the database folder there's migrations and automatically generated schema. The schema is a representation of all the up to date tables with all migrations applied.

In the ios project, in ./resources/database/ there's updates (like migrations) and a .db file. Where's the schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded db browser for sqlite (https://sqlitebrowser.org/dl/) and used it to open the .db file. There I can find all information I might find in a Rails schema.